# How can I resolve 'django_content_type already exists'?

Tags: python, django

After upgrading to django 1.8 I'm recieving the error during migration:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists
```

I'd be interested in the background behind this error, but more importantly,
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Initial migrations on a project can sometimes be troubleshot using --fake-initial

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

It's new in 1.8. In 1.7, --fake-initial was an implicit default, but explicit in 1.8.

From the Docs:

> The --fake-initial option can be used to allow Django to skip an app’s initial migration if all database tables with the names of all models created by all CreateModel operations in that migration already exist. This option is intended for use when first running migrations against a database that preexisted the use of migrations. This option does not, however, check for matching database schema beyond matching table names and so is only safe to use if you are confident that your existing schema matches what is recorded in your initial migration.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial

Comment: Is there any way to do one `manage.py migrate` command that will work on both existing and new databases?

Comment: @RobinWinslow if you want 1 command that works consistently, appending the --fake-initial flag always should work.

Comment: Doesn not help in django 2.1. The error chnges to `column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist`

Comment: When you FAKE the migrations if new changes are done they won't be apply

Answer (score 13):

I solved this issue on Django 2.2.7 or Django 3.0 hosted on Ubuntu 18.04 + Postgres 10.10 version.

> 1. Restore the database in Postgres database (used pgAdmin tool for this)
> 2. (virtualenv)python manage.py loaddata dumpfile.json
> 3. Dropping django_migrations table from database (used pgAdmin tool for this)
> 4. (virtualenv)python manage.py makemigrations
> 5. (virtualenv)python manage.py migrate --fake
> 6. (virtualenv)python manage.py migrate
> 7. (virtualenv)python manage.py collectstatic
> 8. (virtualenv)python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: This worked for me except for the `python manage.py collectstatic` command

Comment: `Django version 4.1.1`, `postgresql-x64-14`, `Windows 11 Home` - worked perfectly, even `python manage.py collectstatic` was not necessary

Answer (score 0):

I granted all privileges to the user on that specific database and it solved the issue.