# Django 1.8 migrate - relation "django_content_type" already exists

Tags: django, postgresql, django-1.8

Any idea why I would be getting this error when I try to migrate?

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type"

I am using using Django 1.8 & PostgreSql

Comment: Removed Thanks and Sig. Added appropriate tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resolve 'django\_content\_type already exists'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760817/how-can-i-resolve-django-content-type-already-exists)

Answer (score 8):

You're going to need to use the `--fake-initial` option when you migrate; it used to be implicit, but has now been made explicit:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial

To quote:

> This option is intended for use when first running migrations against
>   a database that preexisted the use of migrations.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help @FlipperPA but it the migration still doesn't happen. Now I see: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist` . Any ideas? Is it simply a matter of manually creating it?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the problem was, but in Django 1.8, the "name" field on on ContentType has become a property. This caused us issues when migrating to 1.8 in development while some people were still using 1.7. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model Hopefully, that might help point you in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks again mate, i think my migrations are hosed and i have a bit of manual work to do on the db. Will check out the link. Cheers!

Comment: Or just drop your entire database tables and start over.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

1. ./manage.py migrate auth --fake-initial (this throws an error but ignore it)
2. ./manage.py migrate --fake-initial

Comment: This worked for me. But why? Can you please explain me??

Comment: @cjahangir sadly no. i've not dug deep enough to understand what the problem is. it only happens when i'm migrating crusty old pre-1.6 code so I just moved on to bigger things once it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I, like many, don't really understand the problem. I was able to devise a solution that worked for me.

1. Comment out all of your custom installed apps. So, you have just the Django stuff.
2. Migrate only auth: `./manage.py migrate auth`
3. Migrate everything else: `./manage.py migrate`
4. Undo step 1.
5. Migrate all your apps: `./manage.py migrate`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

@Josh's solution worked for me with the following changes. Prior to step 1, I re-added the missing column:

```
ALTER TABLE django_content_type ADD COLUMN name character varying(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'run migrate.py';
```

Running `python manage.py migrate auth` removes this column, presumabley making one or more other changes that failed on some earlier run of `migrate`.

When running `migrate` in step 3 I included the `--fake-initial` flag:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Everything seems to be set right again.