# django 1.8 migrations contenttype integrity error

Tags: django, django-migrations

I upgraded my project from django 1.6 to 1.8. when migrating, I am getting an error with contenttype:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
```

DETAIL:  Failing row contains (31, null, django_auth, adgroup).

I try to migrate contenttype 0002 but it then tells me:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists
```

how do I over ride the first migration file?

Comment: you can  remove this table form your database and re-run the migrations

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resolve 'django\_content\_type already exists'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760817/how-can-i-resolve-django-content-type-already-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your database already has the migrations but django isn't aware of it because multiple reasons (older migrations renamed or deleted, etc.)

What you can do is flatten your older migrations and then fake a migration. So, delete all migrations until your initial migration.

Then, run `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate` (will probably throw an error), and `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`. Here's a link to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial). This is definitely not the best practices but should get you up and running. Initial migrations can sometimes cause weird issues. If that doesn't solve the problem, try it with `--fake` instead of `fake-initial`. Also, I suggest making a dump of the database before embarking on this journey. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you may have `--fake`d the `0002_remove_content_type_name` migration in the `contenttypes` app in error:

```
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
```

You can undo that using:

```
./manage.py migrate contenttypes 0001 --fake
```

and then properly run the `0002` migration so that the name column gets removed from the `contenttypes` table:

```
./manage.py migrate contenttypes
```

then try running the migrations for your app again.

Answer (score 0):

The Django 1.6 database may or may not include South migrations and moving to 1.8 uses the internal migrations.

For me,

```
django-admin.py migrate --fake-initial
```

did the trick.